# Symfony 3 - JS- How to disable a set of checkboxes at the click of a radio button?

Tags: javascript, php, function, symfony, checkbox

in a twig view, which allows me to do statistics I display several things:

A group radio button that allows me to select either "Option A", "Option B", "Both".

And a set of checkboxes referring to user types. They will be displayed through a database query.

Like this :

```
<legend>Type : Sélectionner tout <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" value="selectAll" class="selectAllCheckboxes"></legend>
                    {% for unType in listeTypeUser %}
                    <input type="checkbox" name="typesUser[]" value={{unType.typeUtilisateur}}>{{unType.typeUtilisateur}}<br>       
                    {% endfor %}
```

I already have a function in javascript allowing me to select all and deselect at once.

Now what I would like to do is this:

[image]

If I check "External", then I want that in the list of user types, the type "1st degree" is automatically checked, and that the rest can not be.

And conversely :

[image]

If "CAS" is checked, then all other types have the option to be checked, except the "1st degree" type.

But since I know absolutely nothing about javascript, and I display my user types through a database and I do not write them myself, I do not see how I take it. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Instead of the "hacky" way presented by Florent Destremau below, I would use https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic Javascript. Your html markup should be something like this (meaning the classes)

```html
<div class="radio-button">
<label><input type="radio" name="service" value="cas"/> CAS</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="service" value="external"/> Externe</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="service" value="both"/> Les deux</label>
</div>

<div class="checkboxes">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="circo"/> CIRCO</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="first-degree" data-excluded-check="1"/> 1er degré</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="rectorat"/> Rectorat</label>
</div>
```

And then you can add this bit of JS. I did not test this but you should be able to tweak it gently.

```
<script>
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('.radio-button input');

for (var i = 0; i < radios.length;i++) {
    radios[i].addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        if (this.value == 'cas') {
            checkAllBoxForCas();
        }
    });
}

function checkAllBoxForCas() {
    var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxes input');

    for (var j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++) {
         boxes[j].checked = !boxes[j].dataset.excludedCheck;
    }
}
</script>
```

You can customize this at will, it's fully JS compatible as is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, if for the types of users, I do not write them by hand but I let my database complete this, would it work in the same way?

I will test your function, thank you!

Comment: I edited my answer. You can add any markup from your database so that you can filter out the checkboxes you don't want to be checked